echo get_include_path(); outputting strange value in XAMPP
so I have been having trouble getting files like so:
require_once '../vendor/my-appname/config/file.php';

and I use XAMPP and I put in the following:
echo get_include_path();

and I received this output: C:\xampp\php\PEAR
Is there a way to set this to my htdocs folder? Or is that even what I should do?
I found this:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php
but I would like it to be set globally throughout my programs for anything in the htdocs directory.
I was expecting an output of:
C:\xampp\htdocs\my-appname

Sure, edit the php.ini. That is valid for all files.

Does this answer your question? Setting PHP Include Path on a per site basis?

Btw, what are you including at all? If you have an autoloader you should not include anything, but use namespaces. The vendor directory lets me assume you are using composer.

What is the strange value you're getting?

This answers my original question. Thank you. Now I am realizing it has been trouble with inc files.

I am building a framework and making sure it is compatible with composer.  I developed my own autoloader that is functioning, but right now including files should just simply work.

@brombeer "C:\xampp\php\PEAR"

I solved it. I had a .httaccess file to read .HTML as PHP files. I had to add the .inc.php extension: AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .phtml .html .htm .inc.php @Markus Zeller - thanks for your help.

For the other remark, use the __DIR__ constant: require_once  __DIR__ . '/ ../vendor/my-appname/config/file.php';. Without it may relate to the include path (and under circumstances other, hard to track things). Cf. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php
